# Compiling SDL program written in C.

Tags: c, linux, sdl

I've got problem with compiling SDL program. I've installed SDL dev package according to this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/344512/what-is-the-general-procedure-to-install-development-libraries-in-ubuntu (Method 1). It seems to be completed without any errors. When I'm trying to compile it with such a instruction: `gcc -I/usr/include/SDL/ showimage.c -o out -L/usr/lib -lSDL`

It returns a error:

```
showimage.c:7:23: fatal error: SDL_image.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

Even if I put SDL_image.h to folder from I'm compiling it returns this error:

```
/tmp/ccFiSO10.o: In function `Load_image':
showimage.c:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `IMG_Load'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my code that I recive from my teacher:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"

SDL_Surface* Load_image(char *file_name)
{
        /* Open the image file */
        SDL_Surface* tmp = IMG_Load(file_name);
        if ( tmp == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load %s: %s\n",
                    file_name, SDL_GetError());
                exit(0);
        }
        return tmp;
(....)
```

I know this code is ok, because my friend compiled it and it works fine.

Can anyone help me to compile this?

Answer (score 1):

The first error you're seeing is because the include path is wrong. You set the include path using the -I flag to GCC. Since the include path is incorrect, the SDL header you mention can not be found.

To fix this, set -I to a directory which contains the header you want to use.

The second error comes from the linker, which can't find the IMG_load symbol. This symbol is contained in the SDL libraries, and these libraries need to be supplied to the linker in order for it to find the symbols.

To fix this, you need to set -L to the directory containing the library files of SDL, and you also need to use -l to supply the name of the library to link against.

There's a tool called `pkg-config` which will give you the correct -I -L and -l lines, given a library name. Try running `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl SDL_image`.

--cflags will give you the include parameters, and --libs will give you the library directories and names.

You can include the command in your gcc invocation like this:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl SDL_image` showimage.c -o out
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I'm trying to pkg-config returns this: http://pastebin.com/JZfFBCyH ? I'm sure I installed everything, but that doesn't see anything. I also don't get the first part of your answer. Where should I set -l, you are talking about?

Comment: Ok, I realized that I didn't instal this: libsdl-image1.2-dev. But now if I'm compiling with your line it returns this: http://pastebin.com/qSwng6PB I don't get this...

Answer (score 0):

Add lSDL_image library in linker.

Comment: gcc -I/usr/include/SDL/ showimage.c -o out -L/usr/lib -lSDL -lSDL_image
Like this?